# App Close Event not getting tracked when app is getting Closed using Amplitude Event Tracking

Tags: android, amplitude-analytics

I want to track App Open and App Closed events, Below code i have used. I'm getting App Open Event but i couldn't get App Close Event, is there anyone know how track app close event

```
class AppLifecycleTracker : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks  {
override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if (numActivitiesStarted == 0) {
        // app launched
        Amplitude.getInstance().logEvent("APP_OPEN")
    }
    numActivitiesStarted++
}

override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity?, outState: Bundle?) {
}

override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity?) {
    numActivitiesStarted--
    if (numActivitiesStarted == 0) {
        // app killed
        Amplitude.getInstance().logEvent("APP_CLOSE")
    }
}

override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity?) {
}

override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity?) {
}

private var numActivitiesStarted = 0

override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity?) {

}

override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity?) {

}

}
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's wrong, if you don't post your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not sending any event properties with APP_CLOSE event.

If you are not intending to you could just turn on session event to get automatic **[Amplitude] Start Session** / **[Amplitude] End Session** events in your data without need to maintain your own code for this. Note however these system events cannot carry event properties.

To do this you simply need to call

```
Amplitude.getInstance().trackSessionEvents(true);
```

Comment: i have tried same in ios. but its not working 
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    Amplitude.instance()?.logEvent("APP_CLOSED")}